Debugging Apex code in managed package
We are working on creating a 2GP managed package, and this would be used internally for some of our clients. So we won't be listing this on Appexchange.
Now we have created a private custom setting with a checkbox field. If this checkbox is true, then only the logs get printed in the debug logs. The code in Apex would be something like below:
if (getLogConfig().LogEnabled__c) {
   System.debug('Print something');
}

Now if the package is installed in a client prod environment, I am very sure that the custom setting won't be visible to the client. But let's say that something is not working, and we need to debug the issue, would it be possible for us to change the value of this checkbox to TRUE for the custom setting field from our org?

Managed package debug is always hidden on subscriber orgs unless the debug flags are set on a user by someone logged in to the org via subscriber access. You cannot see debug output from a managed package without the use of subscriber access, which means your package likely needs to appear in your LMA, which in turn means it must pass security review and have an app exchange listing (though the latter can be set private).
